# What is the proper use of the Html.Label?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.label

What is the proper use of this field html helper???

I have the below code in my View, but when displayed it doesn't appear how I expect.

```
<td><@Html.Label("lblLoanType1", "Loan Type : ")</td>
<td><@Html.Label("lblLoanType2", "SBA")</td>
```

Here is the output when displayed in the View:

```
<Loan Type :                       <SBA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra < before @Html that is not necessary

```
<td><@Html.Label
```

should just be

```
<td>@Html.Label
```

Then the rest of the appearance is down to your css.